# Нюансы ORM BITRIX или как преобразовать значение поля

Tags: битрикс, orm

Есть сущность, в ней виртуальное поле задано таким образом в getMap():

```
            'DATE_START_PROP' => array(
            'data_type' => 'string',
            'expression' => array(
                '(SELECT  b_sale_basket_props.VALUE
                    FROM b_sale_basket_props
                    WHERE b_sale_basket_props.BASKET_ID = %s AND b_sale_basket_props.CODE = \'START\')', 'BASKET_ID'
            )
        )
```

В этом поле будет значение типа: 17.06.2017 00:00:00

Каким образом можно преобразовать это значение в этом поле, в дату UNIX (timestamp)?

Делаю таким образом, но выходит ошибка...

```
            new Main\Entity\ExpressionField(
            'DATE_START',
            MakeTimeStamp('%s', "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI:SS"),
            array('DATE_START_PROP'),
            array('data_type' => 'string')
        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете изменить саму карту.

```
'DATE_START_PROP' => array(
    'data_type' => 'datetime',
    ...
```

Т.е. вы смените тип свойства и будуте получать объект даты.

---

Или вы можете добавить конвертацию в timestamp.

```
'expression' => array(
            '(SELECT  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b_sale_basket_props.VALUE)
                FROM b_sale_basket_props
```

---

Или мы можете добавить новое поле к конкретной выборке

```
new Main\Entity\ExpressionField(
        'DATE_START_TIMESTAMP', //другое наименование
        '(SELECT  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b_sale_basket_props.VALUE)
                FROM b_sale_basket_props
                WHERE b_sale_basket_props.BASKET_ID = %s AND b_sale_basket_props.CODE = \'START\')',
        array('BASKET_ID'),
        array('data_type' => 'string')
```